# Remove key value pairs from a map dynamically

Tags: elixir

I have this map stored in a customer variable

```
 %{
     billing_contact: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association:billing_contact is not loaded>,
     billing_contact_id: 305,
     business_contact: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association:business_contact is not loaded>,
     business_contact_id: nil,
     disabled_message: "",
     end_date: nil,
     id: 6851,
     is_disabled: false,
     name: "test",
     start_date: #DateTime<2018-08-17 12:56:50.498078Z>,
     technical_contact: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association:technical_contact is not loaded>,
     technical_contact_id: nil,
     users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>
  }
```

I want to remove all the `key value pairs where value is Ecto.Association.NotLoaded`. I read Map documentation but couldn't find any function to remove key value based on value

I want to do it `dynamically`. So when ever there is a map come in. It automatically remove all the key value pairs where value is Ecto.Association…
I have to send this data to the front end. so need to remove this Ecto.Association.Not loaded key value pairs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#filter/2):

```rb
Enum.filter(input, fn
  {_, %Ecto.Association.NotLoaded{}} -> false
  _ -> true
end)
```

`Ecto.Association.NotLoaded` is a struct, hence it’s easy to pattern match it and reject all the unwanted kv-pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html):

```elixir
for {k, v} <- customer,
    %Ecto.Association.NotLoaded{} != v,
    into: %{}, do: {k, v}
```